# Decode Blob data from sqllite using python

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x, blob

I would like to decode a BLOB data to human readable format. Data is stored in a sqllite database. Being a python newbie I go this far:

```
rows = z.execute("SELECT hex(data) FROM mytables where name = 'something'")
for row in rows: print (row[0])
```

This gives me one row of a BLOB data in the form of a series of thousands of letters with some useful information scattered here and there.

Then, I tried this :

```
   rows = z.execute("SELECT hex(data) FROM mytables where name = 'something'")
    for row in rows: print (row[0]).encode('hex')
```

but the data I get back is still meaningless.This gives me thousands of series of letters except it converted everything into capital letters & numbers , it even converted the previously scattered useful/readable/meaningful information. 
And also throws an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Please advise.

Comment: What does your blob contain, and how do you define human readable?

Comment: `str.encode('hex')` is python2.

Comment: blob is supposed to contain mapping information between two tables. Data is being copied from one table to another. To me human readable is to be able to see this  column information from these two tables along with their data types. I know for a fact that this data exists in the blob.